# trying to understand this query

Tags: sql

```
DECLARE @L_CUSTNMBR VARCHAR(15)
SET @L_CUSTNMBR=(CASE WHEN ISNULL(@CUSTNMBR,'')='' THEN '%' ELSE @CUSTNMBR END)
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (The above code is very product specific.)

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @L_CUSTNMBR VARCHAR(15)
```

Declaring your variable as @L_CUSTNMBR and putting the data type to varchar 15 so this variable can take up to 15 char

```
SET @L_CUSTNMBR=(CASE WHEN ISNULL(@CUSTNMBR,'')='' THEN '%' ELSE @CUSTNMBR END)
```

Assigning the output from your case statement to the variable.  In the case statement it's saying evaluate the variable @customernmbr if it = '' then return % else show the customer number.  The ISNULL function evaluates the variable and if it's null gives it the '' and when its '' it will appear with a % sign based off your THEN statement.